# Routing localhost traffic to external IP address

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra, firewall, pfctl

I have a host with Mac OS and another machine (`192.168.100.50`) in the same LAN.
I would like to configure Mac OS in that way if I access `localhost:443` it will redirect to `192.168.100.50:443`.

I'm able to redirect ports inside Mac OS, so if I access `localhost:444` it redirects to `localhost:443` this way:

1. `sudo sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`
2. `/etc/pf.anchors/dev`:

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 444
```

3. `/etc/pf.conf`:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "dev"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
load anchor "dev" from "/etc/pf.anchors/dev"
```

4. `sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf.conf`

But if I change `from any to 127.0.0.1 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 444` to `from any to 127.0.0.1 port 443 -> 192.168.100.50 port 443` it doesn't work.

I guess I should set up NAT somehow, but I'm not sure how to do that with PF to achieve that. So any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible, you might be better off assigning your Mac a fixed IP address and then redirecting that IP/Port combination elsewhere. 127.0.0.1 is a special and reserved address that is baked into every networkable device, unless I am sadly mistaken changing its behavior might be a bad thing.

Comment: Actually, I'm interested in assigning external IP to localhost name, not 127.0.0.1. Do you think it's impossible?

Comment: they are the same thing

Comment: Actually, Parallels doing it somehow. They are able to route localhost's port to VM.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally managed to solve the task. As Bob Harris [suggested](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250340095?answerId=250641697022&page=1) on Apple's forum, I used ssh tunneling to setup it.

1. On Windows I use [OpenSSH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)
2. On Mac OS I use [Core Tunnel](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/core-tunnel-ssh-tunnel-2/id1354318707?mt=12)
3. Core Tunnel doesn't allow to bind to 443 port directly, so I used another port and redirected 443 to that port via PF as described in initial post.